# Null Space Equals to Column Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone please explain to me why the statement "if $n$ is even, then there exists an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $\text{Null}(A) = \text{Col}(A)$" is true?

Comment: Consider the bock matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&I\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: @vadim123: is it possible to prove the statement with induction starting with a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: Why would you want to use induction?  Just use my construction, with four square submatrices of whatever size you like.